# PHP: в чем преимущество spl_autoload_functions перед обычным подключением с помощью require_once()?

Tags: php, классы, namespace, autoload

Пытаюсь подключить нужные классы в индексный файл с помощью пространства имен:

В файле index.php:

```
use files\Parser;

$obj = new Parser();

$obj->dialMassange;
```

index.php находится на одном уровне с папкой files, в которой лежит Parser.php. В последнем - одноименный класс.

Код не работает, так как нет autoloader, как я понял, он необходим для подключения класса из другого файла, если используется namespace и use. Вот пример из руководства:

```
function libraryTwo($classname) {
    $filename = "../../path/two/". $classname .".php";
    require_once($filename);
}    

spl_autoload_register('libraryOne');
```

Если нужно громоздить такой объем вместо require_once('Parser.php');

то в чем плюс варианта с пространством имен и автолоадером? Быстрее загружаются классы?

Не пойму. Или я чего-то не понял? Объясните, пожалуйста, более компетентные специалисты!

Comment: Вы можете создать файл, который будет загружать только необходимый вам набор библиотек. А потом в проекте просто подключить этот файл

Comment: Если тебе нужно подключить один файл - никакого плюса. Если у тебя проект, где в каждом классе может быть использован любой другой класс, причём не известно заранее какой - плюс налицо